# Use Windows String Ressources from other Project in UI

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have 2 Projects and I want to store the lokalized string resources in my library. So to load the string-resources in the code behind i use something like

```
ResourceLoader l = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("MyLibrary/Resources");
string sample = l.GetString("sample");
```

How can I set the XAML string-ressources like that? I dont want to copy the string resource for every project in the solution.

In other words how to tell my App to use the string-resource in the View from my library?

EDIT:

I am using `Resource.resw` Files in my Windows-Store-Application.
I can acess them through the code behind, but my View in my "MainProject" only presents empty strings and i don't want them to set every string in the code behind at the `Pages` of my "MainProject".

Comment: Open the Resources.resx with the strings in the designer and change the access modifier from internal to public (combobox is in the upper right corner). This might not help didn't read the XAML part :(

Comment: The access is no problem. I can get the complete 'ResourceMap' from "MyLibrary".

Answer (score 0):

First open your `Resource.resx` file and change the access modifier from `internal` to `public`. This will allow you to access entire resource in another project. Now go to the project in which you want to access the `Resource.resx` file. Add the reference of the project which contains `Resource.resx` and include namespace wherever you want to use resource.

Let me know if this doesn't work.

**Edit**:

Please refer to following links. They are explaining how you can refer or access resources.

```
[How to load string resource][1]
```

[Features and restrictions of resource loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465373.aspx) Blockquote

I hope you will find this informative and might solve your problem.

Comment: I am using 'Resource.resw' files. I referenced "MyLibrary" to my Project where i want to display the strings in the XAML Page. I added the namespace, but i get still empty `TextBlocks` in my UI. I think there is a little difference between the .NET `resx` and the `resw` for Windows-Store. I don't find a access modifier, too, not even in the XML View of my 'Resource.resw'. Maybe I missunderstand you, but i want to tell my MainProject to use the 'Resource.resw' of "MyLibrary" like the file would be in my "MainProject".